# Javascript object array initializer formatting

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, resharper

My IDE is visual studio 2015 with Resharper 9.2, I want the javascript object array initializer automatically formated like this

```
var  x = [{
   a: 1,
   b: 2 
},{
   a: 3,
   b: 4 
}];
```

I want the round and square brackets together, Any ideas how can i do this?

It is always formatted like this:

```
var  x = [
    {
       a: 1,
       b: 2 
    },{
       a: 3,
       b: 4 
    }
];
```

Comment: That is some funky white space

Answer (score 3):

You can change the formatting rules of VS as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/999b219z(v=vs.71).aspx).
The problem should be solved by selecting either `block` or `smart`.

Comment: sorry, this doesn't help too much